# how to trigger step function and get the status failed or success

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops

I have been able to use awscli to get start the execution but I need to be able to know when is completed or result is success before it can go to the next step in the pipeline.

`aws stepfunctions start-execution --state-machine-arn arn:aws:states:us-west-2:2xx244xxxx:stateMachine:SamplePipeOrchestration-ftpiles --name SamplePipeOrchestration-ftpiles --input {}  --region us-west-2  --profile sampledev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to develop your own **waiter** in a form a loop which iteratively queries (e.g. every 10s) the status of your execution (e.g. using [describe-execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/stepfunctions/describe-execution.html) and checks for a successful or failed completion.

Comment: Thank you @Marcin, I have looked through stackoverflow and have not find a good example for that to check the status.

Answer (score 1):

```
aws stepfunctions describe-execution --execution-arn arn:aws:states:*
```

Note: You will get the execution arn as output once you will run the start-execution. Use that execution arn in describe-execution to get the status of the step function run.

Answer (score 1):

Inherently, Step Functions invocations are governed by the StartExecution quota. Thus these are the steps:

**Create the State Machine and Provision Resources**

1. Open the Step Functions console and choose Create a state machine.
2. Choose Sample Projects, and then choose Manage a Batch Job.
3. Choose Next.The Deploy resources page is displayed, listing the resources that will be created.
4. Choose Deploy Resources.

*Also Note:*
It can take up to 10 minutes for these resources and related IAM permissions to be created. While the Deploy resources page is displayed, you can open the Stack ID link to see which resources are being provisioned.

**Start a New Execution**

1. On the New execution page, enter an execution name (optional), and then choose Start Execution.
2. (Optional) To identify your execution, you can specify a name for it in the Name box. By default, Step Functions generates a unique execution name automatically.

*Also Note*
Step Functions allows you to create state machine, execution, and activity names that contain non-ASCII characters. These non-ASCII names don't work with Amazon CloudWatch. To ensure that you can track CloudWatch metrics, choose a name that uses only ASCII characters.

3. Optionally, you can go to the newly created state machine on the Step Functions Dashboard, and then choose New execution.
4. When an execution is complete, you can select states on the Visual workflow and browse the Input and Output under Step details.